# [MySQL]: Stored Procedure's and select statements

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm looking into stored procedures at the moment.

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf) article (page 8) in the dev section of the mysql website...

> Ordinarily, it's not normal to put
>   SELECT statements in stored
>   procedures, this is for illustration.
>   I decided that some procedure should
>   simply select from our table, so that
>   when you call the procedure it will be
>   obvious that it's working.

Why is that?

Is using Stored-procedures to simplify complicated select statements not 'best-practices'?

What are some specific situations where it is beneficial to use a stored procedure? Example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally stored procedures are intended for complex processing in the database. There are debates raging about their benefits. I never saw that SELECTs in a stored procedure was a bad thing but I wouldn't expect that every single SQL statement that has to be written goes into a stored procedure either. It should be reserved for those processing that involve multiple statements and will have to be performed repeatedly.

Jeff has a rant about them [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways/).

To answer your direct question for specific examples, I have found that I avoid them because of the portability issue. I attempt to do all my processing application side. At the same time I do not have to worry about network bandwidth in my application so each situation is different.

Comment: I was under the impression that stored procedure's where more portable than a application driven query.  In so far as you can separate your query logic from the application.

Comment: But they are written in the DBMS's own language. SQL Server's stored procedures are written in T-SQL and Oracle's in PL/SQL etc. You cannot move the database from one platform to the next. For some orgs that is not a big deal but for others...

Comment: definitely true... Portability from one DB system to the next is risky.  The pdf I linked outlines some of the mysql-specific syntax/features (as well as several other conventions) that you should avoid in order to maintain compatibility issues on non-mysql based DB's.  BUT, if i'm not mistaken, stored procedure's facilitate portability from one language to the next.

Answer (score 3):

A specific situation where it is beneficial to use Stored Procedure/Routines is that it can provide error checking on parameters similar to functions in OO paradigm.  It gives added 'Encapsulation'

A simple example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_table(IN @id INT)
BEGIN
  IF @id < O THEN
    -- ERROR!  do something here
  ELSEIF
    SELECT * from TABLE WHERE id = @id;
  END IF
END
```